# Bluetooth over serial (SPP) configuration and setup

Tags: linux, bluetooth, protocols, core-bluetooth, yocto

I have an embedded board with an onboard bluetooth capability. My board runs Linux with bluetooth support provided by the BlueZ stack. I have access to all the bluez utils like hciconfig, sdptool, rfcomm, etc.

I need to setup a bluetooth connection configured for supporting only SPP. My intent is to make my board's bluetooth connection discoverable through my iPhone and, when the iPhone pairs with my board's bluetooth connection, it can use serial over bluetooth to send/receive data.

Now, I have done my due research and tried to set this up using the bluez utils without success. I understand that I need to use the RFCOMM capabilities of bluetooth to setup SPP. I am missing something.

Can anyone please outline the steps I need to take to setup/configure SPP and then make my board's bluetooth discoverable with SPP to allow my phone to connect?

Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

iOS apps cannot access legacy profiles such as SPP.  Only the Bluetooth Low Energy GATT profile is available.

The typical approach taken to emulate a serial port using GATT is to use a pair or characteristics; One that is written to and one that "notifies" when there is serial data available.

I don't know how you would go about doing this on the Linux side, but I imagine that you will need some code to advertise the BLE service and manage the characteristics.